# Return from top_k function to image

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVZzS.jpg)I worked on my problem and still I am overwhelmed with many functions. I am looking to use tf.top_k and return to the first image. Could somebody familiar with tensorflow help me to solve this problem?

Question in detail: image (4 by 4) as a tensor --> tf.top_k --> 4 values(2 by 2) and 4 indices(2 by 2) --> snippet --> image (4, 4) as a tensor

For example imagine that we have one image

```
image = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                  [7, 8, 9, 10],
                  [19, 20, 21, 22],
                  [25, 26, 27, 28]])

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, img_height, img_width, 1], name='x')
patches = tf.extract_image_patches(x, [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], "SAME")
ktop, indices = tf.nn.top_k(patches, k=4, sorted=True, name=None)
```

Now I am looking to give ktop and indices to get image again like the first state

```
image = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                  [7, 8, 9, 10],
                  [19, 20, 21, 22],
                  [25, 26, 27, 28]])
```

I tried many things such as tf.one_hot, tf.gatter, and so on but I could not get a (4, 4) image. I should have a tensor in input and output and it seems that I can not use numpy or for loops. I asked similar question before but I ask here again with more clear explanation. 
Could you please somebody help to solve this question. It should be easy for others but for me its difficult.

This snippet gave me the first image but not as (1, 4, 4, 1) and instead it give as (2, 2, 2, 2) or other shapes.

```
z1 = tf.assign(z1, tf.reshape(tf.gather(ktop[0, 0, 0, :], [indices[0, 0, 0, :]]), [2, 2]))
z2 = tf.assign(z2, tf.reshape(tf.gather(ktop[0, 0, 1, :], [indices[0, 0, 1, :]]), [2, 2]))
z3 = tf.assign(z3, tf.reshape(tf.gather(ktop[0, 1, 0, :], [indices[0, 1, 0, :]]), [2, 2]))
z4 = tf.assign(z4, tf.reshape(tf.gather(ktop[0, 1, 1, :], [indices[0, 1, 1, :]]), [2, 2]))

z = tf.concat([[z1, z2], [z3, z4]], 0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, how do you expect to go from 2x2x4 to 4x4x1 ? what is `snippet`?

Comment: thanks for answer. If you run my snippet, it gives a (1, 4, 4, 1) image as x. Then it provide 8 tensors from top_k: four value(1, 2, 2, 4) and four indices(1, 2, 2, 4).  Now, I want to return to image (1, 4, 4, 1). Its my question? One possible solution in my head is to Upsample each value[0, :, :, 0], value[0, :, :, 1], ... value using corresponding indices and get 4 tensor of (1, 4, 4, 1) each contain values and zeros between. Then combine them to reach the first image. I do not know how to do that though?

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of a clear explanation of how you want to go from the 2x2x4 tensors to the 4x4x1 I can only suggest this:

```
img_out = tf.reshape(ktop, [-1, 4, 4, 1])
```

Comment: I added my snippet for return. If it was MATLAB, I could add for loops and everything could be solved easily but with Tensorflow its difficult. Your snippet will change the shape of top_k but without using indices.

Comment: I added an image in my question, you can click on the link to see. In that image I explained my question in detail with one example. Would you please have a look at that and advice with any snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer which TENSORFLOW followers did not replay so far. For returning from top_k to image we should use depth_to_space function:

output_image = tf.depth_to_space(
    output_image,
    2,
    name=None,
    data_format='NHWC'
)